# How to subclass coroutine?

Tags: python, oop, python-asyncio

I want my class `MyCoro` to behave as same as coroutine. I am looking for something like this as class definition:

```py
class MyCoro(Coroutine?):
    def __init__(self, text):
        async def coro():
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print(text)

        super().__init__(coro())
```

So that I can use it like this:

```py
asyncio.create_task(MyCoro("Hello!"))

# Above is same as:

async def coro(text):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(text)

asyncio.create_task(coro("Hello!"))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class with an async `__call__` method, like:

```
import asyncio

class Coroutine:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    async def __call__(self):
        for i, word in enumerate(self.text.split()):
            print(' '*i, word)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    coro = Coroutine("it's time to light the lights")
    await coro()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Noting, of course, that you don't actually need to call `create_task`; you could rewrite `main` like this:

```
async def main():
    coro = MyCoroutine("it's time to light the lights")
    await coro()
```

Comment: yep, that is what I was looking for. I was thinking it would be overcomplicated to do so, but totally forgot coroutine is just an async function. Thanks!